# How can I change this super call to pass the arguments explicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-2.3

I'm running a legacy `Rails 2.3` (yes, I know) application on a new VM. It's running `Ruby v2.3.1`. I've made all of the recommended changes to get this old app running on this version. Everything runs great, and much faster, except for this code. This code is from the old `Advanced Recipes for Rails` book and is `error_handling_form_builder.rb`.

First, here's the form declaration:

```
<% form_for(:review, :builder => ErrorHandlingFormBuilder) do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :system_id, @systems, :id, :name, { :include_blank => "Select a Standard"}, { :onchange => remote_function(:url => { :action => :makes }, :submit => :text, :method => 'post') } %>
    <div id="categoriesdiv">
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This code works fine if I remove the builder param. Here's the code from `ErrorHandlingFormBuilder`:

```
helpers = field_helpers +
          %w(date_select datetime_select calendar_date_select time_select collection_select) +
          %w(collection_select select country_select time_zone_select) -
          %w(label fields_for)

helpers.each do |name|
  # We don't want to have a label for a hidden field
  next if name=="hidden_field"
  define_method name do |field, *args|
    options = args.detect {|argument| argument.is_a?(Hash)} || {}
    build_shell(field, options) do
      super # This call fails
    end
  end
end
```

The call to `super` above fails with following error:

```
implicit argument passing of super from method defined by define_method()
is not supported. Specify all arguments explicitly.
```

Looking at the code, I'm not sure how to change it.

I know I have to call super with the explicit arguments, but I tried this:

```
super(field, options)
```

and I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 4..6)
```

I also tried:

```
build_shell(field, options) do
  super(*args)
end
```

but I get:

```
undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol
Did you mean?  tap
```

It seems like it's looking for the `collection` attribute 2nd in the list of `*args`. But it's first. If i pass `field` as the first argument though, I get a `Stack Level Too Deep`.

Comment: try `super(*args)` instead

Comment: It tried it. Updated question with results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super` without an argument list resends the current message, starting message dispatch at the superclass, passing along the exact same arguments that were passed to the current method.

In your case, the arguments being passed to the current method are `(field, *args)`, so `super` without an argument list would pass along `(field, *args)`, but unfortunately `super` without an argument list doesn't work inside `define_method`, so you have to pass along the arguments explicitly using `super(field, *args)`.

This will call the method with the name given by `name` in the superclass passing along `(field, *args)` just as if you had called `super` without an argument list.

> Looking at the code, I'm not sure how to change it.

Simple: since `super` without an argument list implicitly passes along the arguments exactly as they were passed, the *explicit* equivalent to that is to just copy&paste the parameter list from the method definition into the argument list of `super`. In this case the method definition is `define_method(name) do |field, *args| … end`, so the parameter list is `(field, *args)`, and you just copy that into the argument list for `super`: `super(field, *args)`.

It may or may not be possible (and desirable) to pass *different* arguments, depending on how the method is designed, and how you process the arguments, but this *always* works. (Or, put it another way: if this doesn't work, then the original code using just `super` also doesn't work. The only exception is when you want to pass along a block and you don't capture that block into a `Proc`, you will have to modify the method signature to add an `&blk` parameter.)

Comment: I tried passing ```field, *args```, but unfortunately this code will not run on ruby >= ```2.1``` apparently. Passing the arguments explicitly simply gives a ```Stack Level Too Deep``` error. So there is no way to make this old 2.3 application run on a newer version of ruby.

Comment: I especially appreciate the last sentence. I was wondering about that.